# How to incorporate custom theme js files into Nuxt

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am attempting to use a [purchased Bootstrap theme](https://themeforest.net/item/icare-charity-nonprofit-and-fundraising-wordpress-theme/8776117) (because I am design challenged) into a Nuxt site. I have managed to get all of the scss/css files included, but I'm having problems finding a way to get the custom .js files to be added as well. The theme itself uses jQuery, and the two files are all jQuery functions. I've added `bootstrap-vue` and `jQuery` from npm, and I've tried adding the files in the `script` item in the `head` section in `nuxt.config.js like so using the`assets` directory;

```
head{
    script: [
      { src: '~assets/js/min/plugins.min.js' },
      { src: '~assets/js/min/custom.min.js' },
      { src: '~assets/js/min/modernizr.min.js' },
    ],
}
```

and like so using the `static` directory

```
head{
    script: [
      { src: 'js/min/plugins.min.js' },
      { src: 'js/min/custom.min.js' },
      { src: 'js/min/modernizr.min.js' },
    ],
}
```

but either way, I keep getting a `jQuery is not defined error`.

Is there another way to load these files so that they have access to jQuery? Search results seem to indicate that maybe I should use a plugin, but I'm not sure how to do that just to add a local js file.

Comment: Hey @wonder95, just to make sure: Does your plugins.mins.js iclude jQuery? And when is the first time you try to access it? Is it in a component, or is it your theme, that is trying to use jQuery. If so, in which .js file is jQuery called?

Comment: @Merc No, they don't specifically inclue jQuery. It looks like they just assume that it is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have just a `/` missing?
Assuming you have this folder sturcture:

`/static/js/modernizr-custom.js`

You could include it:

```
head: {
  ...
  script: [
    { src: '/js/modernizr-custom.js' }
  ]
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Also it is of course mandatory that if your plugin.js is using `jQuery` that you actually load jQuery.

To do that, just include jQuery in the same way to your scripts in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
head: {
  ...
  script: [
    { src: '/js/jquery.min.js' },
    { src: '/js/plugin.js' }
  ]
}
```

This means you have to download jquery and put it into your static directory.
Alternatively you could use a CND to load jquery from. (This makes sense, because other pages might have loaded jquery from the same cdn and you have it already cached).

`{ src: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js }`

Comment: Yeah, I tried both ways, but the leading slash didn't make a difference.

Comment: That is very weird. I just checked and this is how I included js files in the past into nuxt projects. Can you check if jQuery is just not defined when trying to use it, but the script are in fact in the head and loaded? Maybe you use jQuery before the scripts in the head are requested?
Some code, about where you use jQuery could help to spot the problem – or of course, if it is indeed a problem of the scripts not being loaded because the links are broken, then we need to solve that...
I personally think it is a timing issue

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but they are included in the page like so : `<script data-n-head="ssr" src="/js/min/plugins.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That looks fine as long as the source file is found. Try to check your browsers network tab to see if the file is actually loaded (no 404). If that is the case, then I am sure it is a timing problem.
Another test you can make is this: open your browsers console after loading the page and type: `jQuery` and hit enter. If it returns a function you see that jQuery is available and probably your app is just using it too early before it is loaded...

Comment: Also I just saw your answer above: `@Merc No, they don't specifically inclue jQuery. It looks like they just assume that it is loaded.` If they don't load it, and you don't either, You of course have to make sure it is loaded. If there is no `jQuery`, it makes absolutely sense that whenever the theme's code tries to access `jQuery` (undefined), it will throw an error.
Just include it as well in your scripts...

Comment: Well, since I have `jquery` installed via npm, and I have it would seem logical that it's already loaded via Nuxt, correct?. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Installing via npm does not mean that it is also loaded in your project. Installing just means that jquery files are added to your `node_modules` folder. After that you have to either include the files (or with other packages you probably want to use ES6 imports)...

Comment: I edited the answer. I think this should solve your problem. you don't need the npm install anymore. Normally you could include jQuery like `import jQuery from "jquery";` in your components,if you have an npm package installed. In this case it's a bit different, because it's the plugin that uses jQuery...